# ¿Cómo contar registros cuando hay una subconsulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente requiero contar todos aquellos registros que tengan su Género (sexo) correcto, para ello, estoy comparando que el Género que se ingresó a la BDD contra una tabla de Géneros x Nombre que está en la misma BDD. El query que tengo es el siguiente:

```
select count (case when [Genero] = (select g.Genero
              from [dbo].[Generos] as g
              where g.[Nombre] = SUBSTRING( ltrim([Customer Name]),1,CHARINDEX(' ',ltrim([Customer Name])) )  )
              then [Genero] end) as Genero
from [dbo].[BDDPpal]
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

## Ejemplo

Tbl Generos:

```
Nombre -- Genero
Andres -- Masculino
Ana -- Femenino
Carlos -- Masculino
Jose -- Masculino
```

Tbl BDDPpal:

```
[Customer Name] -- [Genero]
Ana -- Masculino
Carlos -- Femenino
Andres -- Masculino
Jose -- Masculino
```

El resultado debería ser 2 (en integer, Que indica que en la BDDPpal hay 2 registros que tienen el género correctamente ingresado luego de ser validado contra la tabla Generos)

Alguna sugerencia acerca de cómo puedo lograr contar los Géneros correctos luego de ser validados contra la tabla de Géneros?

Comment: La verdad es que no consigo entender qué es lo que tratas de obtener. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo con datos?

Comment: *Tbl Generos:

Nombre -- Genero
Andres -- Masculino
Ana -- Femenino
Carlos -- Masculino
Jose -- Masculino

*Tbl BDDPpal:

[Customer Name] -- [Genero]
Ana -- Masculino
Carlos -- Femenino
Andres -- Masculino
Jose -- Masculino

El resultado debería ser 2 (en integer, Que indica que en la BDDPpal hay 2 registros que  tienen el género correctamente ingresado luego de ser validado contra la tabla Generos)

Answer (score 0):

Para el ejemplo de datos que pones deberías hacer una consulta cruzando las dos tablas con un `INNER JOIN` y contar los registros resultantes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Generos
INNER JOIN BDDPpal ON Generos.Nombre =  BDDPpal.[Customer Name]
    AND Generos.Genero = BDDPpal.Genero
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:

```
SELECT g.Genero,COUNT(*)
FROM Generos g
left OUTER JOIN BDDPpal p ON g.Nombre =  p.[Customer Name] AND g.Genero = p.Genero
GROUP BY g.Genero
```